# is this a valid javascript design pattern when many instances are required?

Tags: design-patterns, javascript

I have some code that I'm refactoring, right now its just a list of functions, primarily jQuery.

The code is a form builder. The user adds sections, questions etc using jqueryUI drag/drop/sort. They can get quite long in the range of > 1k questions. I've been debating between patterns,frameworks, etc. and have settled on what I believe will be the best improvement without ripping everything out and starting completely over with something like angular or react.

I was also considering the module pattern but I'm concerned about having so many duplicates of the methods in memory (>1k) and thought this might serve me better. Is there anything I'm overlooking or gotchas that might cause an issue? I like that its all wrapped inside an IIFE and feels encapsulated.

Pattern example:

```
var Question = (function() {

    function Question(name, type) {
        // enforces new
        if (!(this instanceof Question)) {
            return new Question(name,type);
        }

        // constructor body
        this.name = name || 'default' ;
        this.type = type || 'text';
    }

    Question.prototype.someMethod = function(arg) {
        // method body
    }

    return Question;
}());
```

it would be used like so:

```
Question question1 = new Question('name','picklist');
```

Comment: Will some cases have local variables/class private fields? If not, the outer anonymous function & var assignment can be done away with.

Comment: I was about to abort reading your question and just dropping a comment about angular, but then you mentioned that you do not want to use it. I do not quite understand your reasoning about the necessity to rip everything apart, because angular is supposedly built to integrate well with other frameworks, it even includes a jQuery subset. You talk about patterns and frameworks (higher level abstractions), but your solution is nothing but a class in javascript. That's like answering _"Are you using angular or jQuery?_" with "_no, variables work much better for me_"

Comment: @null I suppose I shouldn't discount angular entirely. When I thought of angular I immediately thought of things like: dependency injection, directives, isolate scope, etc. Unfortunately I've only really played around with angular and am concerned about the ramp up time to learn/re-learn even the basics of the framework. If you were in my place would you still consider going this direction?

Comment: @outis thanks, yeah I should probably start with the stripped down version and add that if needed.

Comment: @null also somewhat intimidated on getting jqueryUI sortable/draggable/droppable to play nice with angular. I know there are angular-style libraries for draggable/droppable but haven't seen one that covers drag/drop/sort.

Comment: I see, the "everything" that would have to be torn apart is not what you presented in your question but other functionality.

Comment: @null huh? i mentioned the jqueryUI drag/drop/sort in my question

Comment: Hence my confusion about your proposed use of classes as a possible solution while also mentioning possible conflicts with existing functionality that appears to be unrelated to the use of classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any OO-principles that are practically applicable for Javascript?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180585/are-there-any-oo-principles-that-are-practically-applicable-for-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you've cited in your example is just fine, although in your case, not really required. The idea of the module pattern is to hide away the things you don't explicitly return. So in your case, your IIFE isn't really doing anything (if you had private helpers inside your modules, however, you would).

If you have common methods which are shared among components (for example, all form elements may have a `getValue()` method, you can use JavaScript's prototypal inheritance to create a parent object, and have the various form elements inherit from it:

```
function FormObject() {}
FormObject.prototype.getValue = function() { return 42; };

function Question() {
    // ...
}
Question.prototype = Object.create(FormObject);
Question.prototype.constructor = Question;
```

This ugliness can be resolved with ES6's `class` feature, which is syntactic sugar to all of that:

```
class FormObject {
    // FormObject generic implementation here
}
class Question extends FormObject {
    constructor() {
        // ...
    }
    someMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
var question1 = new Question(...);
```

---

Also, if you're into modules, have a look at **[Browserify](http://browserify.org/)** and **[webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)**. For ES6 today, have a look at **[Babel](https://babeljs.io/)**.

#### formObject.js

```
class FormObject {
    // FormObject generic implementation here
}
module.exports = FormObject;
```

#### question.js

```
var FormObject = require('./formObject');
class Question extends FormObject {
    constructor() {
        // ...
    }
    someMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
module.exports = Question;
```

#### main.js

```
require('./question.js');
var question1 = new Question(...);
```