# Best practice to callbacks in OOP (JavaScript)?

Tags: object-oriented, javascript, object-oriented-design, asynchronous-programming, callbacks

For anyone who uses callbacks, how do I approach it when the method is an asynchronous setter?

Here's an example

```
class API
{
  constructor()
  {
     this.token = null;
  }
  refreshToken(callback)
  {
    request("http://api.com/token", (token) => {
      this.token = token;
      callback(token);
    });
  }
}
```

What would be the point of returning the token if I've already set it in the object's property?

I find myself dumbfounded when I end up doing something like this:

```
api.refreshToken((token) => {
  //callback is used as a 'wait until token arrives' for proceeding code
  request("http://api.com/data?token=" + token);
});
```

But I need it as an object property so that I can reuse the token, such as:
`request("http://api.com/data?token=" + this.token);`

But now I have two variables for the same thing, provided by OOP's property and the callback. It's a pretty stupid problem, but I need direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any OO-principles that are practically applicable for Javascript?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180585/are-there-any-oo-principles-that-are-practically-applicable-for-javascript)

Comment: It stores the token so you don't have to. The callback is a signal that something happened. You don't need to use the arg right away.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Or do I assign the token in the method's callback to justify using the argument? Feels like I might be pondering on how "atomic" each function should be.

Comment: You wouldn't even need to have a token class member unless you intend to cache it.  Simply assigning it is unnecessary until you actually use it outside of the context of the callback.

Comment: @Neil I did say `so that I can reuse the token`...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently *wrong* with this. If provided an argument I feel like `getToken` is a more appropriate method name, which could call `refreshToken` if required:

```js
class API {
    constructor() {
        this.token = null;
    }
    getToken(callback) {
        if (this.tokenIsValid()) {
            callback(this.token);
        } else {
            this.refreshToken((token) => {
                this.token = token;
                callback(token);
            });
        }
    }
    tokenIsValid() {
        // ...
    }
    refreshToken(callback) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now a `token` argument makes sense:

```js
api.getToken(token => {
    request("http://api.com/data?token=" + token);
});
```

Refreshing the token is an implementation detail that should not be leaking out to code using your class. Give outside code a `getToken` method. Refreshing the token is not the responsibility of the code using your `API` class. They only need to get the token, and they shouldn't have to care if the token is stale and needs to be renewed.

The big advantage here is you are free to refactor the API class to change how it handles tokens, and prevent downstream changes in code using the API class.

This would be called [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: Damn, this seems like a better approach than my auto-refresher. Thanks for the answer, I will wait for more though.

Comment: @Vic: This isn't a replacement for the auto-refresher. Instead it is an augmentation of that feature, separating the "refresh token" part from the "get token" part to clarify how your api object should be used.