# Object.defineProperty vs get/set

Tags: javascript

What is the difference and when would you prefer to use `Object.defineProperty` vs `get`/`set` methods in javascript for getters / setters?

Ex:

```
class Foo {
    constructor () {
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'bar', {
            get () {
                return this._bar;
            },
            set (value) {
                this._bar = value;
                this.extraFunctionCall();
            }
        })
    }
}
```

vs

```
class Foo {
    get bar () {
        return this._bar;
    }

    set bar (value) {
        this._bar = value;
        this.extraFunctionCall();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any OO-principles that are practically applicable for Javascript?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180585/are-there-any-oo-principles-that-are-practically-applicable-for-javascript)

Comment: `Object.defineProperty` doesn't have to be used within the scope of the class. You can call it at any time on any object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They end up being the same. The first is simply a self inflicted [monkey patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) version of the second.

There really is no reason to do the first this way other than to show off.

That isn't to say that `defineProperty()` doesn't have proper uses. But this does it in the constructor and with a fixed string. The net result is same behavior and no more flexibility then we have in the second while being less readable.

This reminds me of java's reflection. There is a lot of dangerous power here. Plenty of rope to hang yourself with. Don't mess with this without a good reason.

Answer (score 3):

defineProperty is useful when adding getters/setters for an object that already exists.

However the latter is better for when adding getters/setters to your class, or when you’re creating your Object.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not correct.

## Instance vs prototype

By using `Object.defineProperty` you are defining the property on the **instance** of the class. When you use a getter/setter, the property is set on the **prototype**.

This means that in your case, `Object.hasOwnProperty` will return `true` with
`Object.defineProperty` and `false` with the getter/setter.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor () {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'bar', {
      get () {
        return this._bar;
      },
      set (value) {
        this._bar = value;
        this.extraFunctionCall();
      }
    });
  }

  get baz () {
    return this._baz;
  }

  set baz (value) {
    this._baz = value;
    this.extraFunctionCall();
  }
}

const myFoo = new Foo();
console.log('bar', myFoo.hasOwnProperty('bar'));   // true
console.log('baz', myFoo.hasOwnProperty('baz'));   // false
```

## Object.defineProperty use case

`Object.defineProperty` is useful when you want to programmatically define more than one property the same way.

For example, I have found it useful when creating Custom Elements because I need to create a lot of properties with the same getter/setter pattern.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    const defineProperty = property =>
      Object.defineProperty(this, property, {
        get() {
          /* getter definition */
        },
        set(value) {
          /* setter definition */
        },
      });

    defineProperty('bar');
    defineProperty('baz');
  }
}
```

Here I can define a getter/setter for `bar` and `baz` without having to duplicate the code.

As far as I know, there is no way to do this using the getter/setter syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The only real usecase for 'defineProperty' in a constructor is, if you want to use the options for 'enumerable' etc.