# Develop for MySQL and SQLite3 Concurrently

Tags: javascript, database, mysql, sqlite

I am developing a javascript (Node.js) desktop program that works with an existing MySQL database. I would like to (eventually) distribute to others with based on SQLite, or MySQL if they need (or possibly some other database).

What is a good strategy for writing database agnostic code? I'm baking in switches like the pseudo-code below, but I think there's a better way to abstract this out:

```
result = query1();

function query1(){
  DbType = getDbType(); // Returns MySQL or SQLite
  if DbType == 'MySQL'{
    query = ""; // MySQL Query
    result = mysqlconnector.doquery(query);
  }else{
  if DbType == 'SQLite'{
    query = ""; // SQLite Query
    result = sqliteconnector.doquery(query);
  }
  return result;
}
```

I don't think I want a full-blows ORM as they seem annoyingly restrictive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any OO-principles that are practically applicable for Javascript?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180585/are-there-any-oo-principles-that-are-practically-applicable-for-javascript)

Comment: How exactly? I'm missing what in those asnwers applies here?

Comment: Inversion of Control.  Specifically define some interface (I'll call it `IDataStoreAccessor` to make this easier) that would have functions like `getFoo(id)` or `saveFoo(foo)`.  Then everywhere you need to access a data store, pass in an object that implements that interface.  Then when you want to swap data stores you simply change whatever supplies your code with `IDataStoreAccessor`s with a different implementation.  Your code doesn't care that a switch happened and will just keep on working.  Then when you decide to expand to a new data store, you just make a new accessor and away you go.

Comment: Use a Factory method to return the proper connector.  See http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/factory-method-design-pattern

Answer (score 1):

As @Becuzz suggested, in many OO languages you would create an interface and implement a SQLite and MySQL implementation. In JavaScript you don't have interfaces, but the principle is the same.

Create two JavaScript objects that have the same functions defined on each:

```
function mySqlDao(connector) {
  return {
    query1: function() {
      // query mysql
      return connector.doquery("...")
    }
  }
}

function sqliteDao(connector) {
  return {
    query1: function() {
      // query sqlite
      return connector.doquery("...")
    }
  }
}
```

Where you want to run a query, inject a DAO

```
function foo(dao) {
  return {
    bar: function() {
      const foos = dao.query1()
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

And at your composition root you construct your DAO.

```
const dbType = getDbType()
const dao = dbType === 'MySQL' ? mySqlDao(mysqlconnector) :
  sqliteDao(sqliteconnector)
const myFoo = foo(dao)
```

Comment: Looks promising... but still working through the logic (I'm still figuring out JS). Particularly `const foo = dao => ({` is tripping me up

Comment: @Trees4theForest it assigns a function with a single parameter `dao` to `foo`. I've edited my answer to use the traditional syntax instead of arrow functions.

Comment: Got it, that makes it a little clearer. Thanks for your patience